# Validating React form in componentDidUpdate()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I have a form that uses immense amount of logic with auto-filling fields, depending on user input etc.
In addition, I need to provide live validation while user is typing.

I used to call validators manually, depending on what fields setState() would update, but very soon that became unmaintainable. I then created a function that calls all validator methods I have, and manually invoke it every time I update the state.

Now I think about going further, and automate invoking that function. I want to implement this using
`componentDidUpdate()` react lifecycle method.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {  
  if (_.isEqual(prevState.data, this.state.data))
    return;
  this.validateAll();
}
```

Now, if any of the form field changed - we run full validation to be sure, that we didn't forget anything. The problem though is that lodash `_.isEqual()` is a costly deep-comparision operation, and `componentDidUpdate()`  lifecycle method is invoked on any user input, so this can potentially lead to performance issues.

I decided to reduce amount of that comparisons as well as amount of validation function invocations by debouncing.

```
handleValidation = (prevState) => {
  if (_.isEqual(prevState.data, this.state.data))
    return;
  this.validateAll();
};

debouncedHandleValidation = _.debounce(this.handleValidation, 200);

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  this.debouncedHandleValidation(prevState);
}
```

Here is a [Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vhya6r) (calls to deep compare and validation are logged)

**My question is:** is it okay to handle form validation this way, or there is something I didn't take 
 into account and my approach is bad?

Thanks.

Comment: `componentDidUpdate()` is not a react hook, it is a lifecycle method. I might be being pedantic, but I think it is worth knowing the difference.

Comment: @evolutionxbox thank you, fixed - my php past made me call it that way ;]

Answer (score 0):

The most common pattern for handling validation of forms in react is to check if the input is valid in its `onChange` props.

One of the reason is fairly obvious, you'll want to set both validation errors and value simultaneously.

Another obvious reason is that conceptually the validation *belongs to the mutation on the input, not the update lifecycle of the component*.

Additionally, if you are not using hooks, this will work even if you are using a functional component.

All the above, without the cost of deep comparisons.

Example:

```
handleChange = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const { name, value } = event.target;
  let errors = this.state.errors;

  switch (name) {
    case 'fullName': 
      errors.fullName = 
        value.length < 5
          ? 'Full Name must be 5 characters long!'
          : '';
      break;
    case 'email': 
      errors.email = 
        validEmailRegex.test(value)
          ? ''
          : 'Email is not valid!';
      break;
    case 'password': 
      errors.password = 
        value.length < 8
          ? 'Password must be 8 characters long!'
          : '';
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }

  this.setState({errors, [name]: value}, ()=> {
      console.log(errors)
  })
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that stuff before, unfortunately this will not work in my case, because some of the data is not directly input by user, but is fetched from server (depending on what user enter in other fields) and is set into state. That fetched data also need validation (at least to remove error messages from fields that user entered incorrectly and now they are correct).
But thank you anyway

Comment: That's the same, you'll validate those datas while evaluating It and before sending It to your state. Take a look at validation parts of Formik and redux-form

Comment: It is an interesting idea, but validity of some data depends on state. (one field must be required if other field is filled). There are also possibilities, that both of that fields will simultaneously come in one fetch from the server, and thus state must be set before validation. (or I will need to write additional validation logic, which sounds very bad)

Comment: also he check on the data IMHO has to be done before setting the stat e with new data. It Is not possibile to have parallel concurrencies in setState(), of you encounter some, you are probably apllying an antipattern

Comment: Sorry for the typos, I'm on my mobile :)